# Swift - Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I got this error message when I try to return the value.

> /Users/MNurdin/Documents/iOS/xxxxx/RangeSlider.swift:76:109:
>   Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider
>   breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

My code

```
var minimumValue: Float = 0.0
var maximumValue: Float = 1.0
var minimumRange: Float = 0.0
var selectedMinimumValue: Float = 0.2
var selectedMaximumValue: Float = 0.8

var distanceFromCenter: Float = 0.0

var _padding: Float = 20

/**/

func xForValue(value: Float){
    return (self.frame.size.width-(_padding*2))*((value - minimumValue) / (maximumValue - minimumValue))+_padding; //error here
}

func valueForX(x: Float){
    return minimumValue + (x-_padding) / (self.frame.size.width-(_padding*2)) * (maximumValue - minimumValue); //error here
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is that your real code? Your functions have no return type defined, but call `return`. That should not compile.

Comment: yes, that is my real code.

Comment: But  `func xForValue(value: Float) { return 1.0 }` already gives a compiler error "unexpected non-void return value in void function".

Comment: Why are you using Float and not Double?

Comment: @MartinR I already fix it. sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'm more prefer float instead double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a return types for functions and cast `CGFloat` to `Float`

```
func xForValue(value: Float) -> Float {
    return (Float(self.frame.size.width) - (_padding * 2)) * ((value - minimumValue) / (maximumValue - minimumValue)) + _padding;
}

func valueForX(x: Float) -> Float {
    return minimumValue + (x - _padding) / (Float(self.frame.size.width) - (_padding * 2)) * (maximumValue - minimumValue);
}
```